# Is there a difference between "be honest to" and "be honest with"?

Tags: grammar

I have seen [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/honest%20with%20%28someone%29) that the expression *"to be honest **with** someone"* exists and means telling someone the truth. I also have seen sentences like *"be honest **to** yourself."* and *"be honest **to** me."* My question is, are both *"to be honest to someone"* and *"to be honest with someone"* correct? If so, is there a difference between the two?

Answer (score 1):

"Be honest *to* me" is not idiomatic. I've certainly never heard it, and it was a surprise to me (native British English speaker) to find any credible search results at all. It appears it is occasionally used, but [this ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=be%20honest%20with%2C%20be%20honest%20to&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbe%20honest%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbe%20honest%20to%3B%2Cc0) shows that it is extremely rare in comparison to "be honest *with".

You may be thinking of examples such as "talk to" versus "talk with", both of which are idiomatic and are sometimes freely interchangeable but with slightly different inferences. You can talk *to* somebody without them saying much (or anything) back. To talk *with* somebody infers that you both spoke - you had a conversation.

Although by saying "be honest with me" you are asking someone to *speak* honestly, honesty itself not a verb like "talk". The verb is "be", and what is idiomatic seems to be driven by how one would show or express the particular quality you are asking someone to be.